# Hot to write a custom validator with apache bval

Tags: java, bean-validation

I am using bean-validation with apache bval as its implementation. (I do not want to use hibernate-validation or oval, because they have too much dependencies.)

First question: Is bval still maintained or is it orphaned?

Second question: Is it possible to implement custom validators using bval? E.g. a need a validator to `File` field that validates, that the file exists, isreadable and a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache BVal is afaik compliant with Bean Validation 1.0 which means should be able to write portable custom constraints. However, BVal is not yet Bean Validation 1.1 compatible, meaning you won't have executable constraints.

I don't know how active development is atm. Last release was in September 2012 which is quite a while back.

What is your concern with the Hibernate Validator or OVal dependencies?

Comment: Regarding maven central oval depends on many other things like spring, groovy, ... . I have a lightweighted project and I do not need groovy or spring (for this project). But after taking a deeper look on oval, it seems to be very scalable, so currently I can use it without any (new) dependency; and for now I like it.

Comment: Hi, Hibernate Validator does not have that many dependencies actually. It only requires JBoss Logging, a small type resolution library named ClassMate and a Unified EL implementation. The latter can easily be made superfluous by using a custom message interpolator.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody did a performance comparison. However I am not sure how objective this comparison is: http://soularis999.blogspot.com/2011/07/bean-validation-performance-evaluation.html

Comment: Your link doesn't answer either part of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a how to now on baeldung.com: https://www.baeldung.com/apache-bval, it looks pretty standard

- define an new annotation describing your constraint
- define an constraint validator which `implements ConstraintValidator<CONSTRAINT, TARGET>`
- annotatate your annotation with `@Constraint(validatedBy={Validator.class})`